# Using Microsoft Fakes I get a compile error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to use Microsoft Fakes to shim the `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` call.

When I use the code below it gives me a compile error saying:

> The property or indexer
>   'System.IO.Fakes.ShimDirectory.CreateDirectoryString'  cannot be used
>   in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Here is the code I am trying to run that is causing the compile issues:

```
    _path = @"\\" + TestConfig.Instance.FileShareHost + @"\SharingIsGood";
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ShimDirectory.CreateDirectoryString(_path);

        // Directory.CreateDirectory(_path);
        _fatalException = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHandleFatalExceptions>();
        _filter = "*.txt";
        _fileReader = new FileHandler();
    }
```

If I remove the `ShimDirectory.CreateDirectoryString(_path);` line, it compiles fine. So something with that line is strange. I'm new to Microsoft Fakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create a fake for `ShimDirectory.CreateDirectoryString`, your code should look like:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    ShimDirectory.CreateDirectoryString = path =>
    {
      // Your fake code here
    }

    _path = @"\\" + TestConfig.Instance.FileShareHost + @"\SharingIsGood";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(_path);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what to put in the fake section.  I thought `ShimDirectory.CreateDirectoryString` was the same as `Directory.CreateDirectory`. Kind of confused here.

Comment: Okay. I got it to compile. Still having other issues with it.  I will edit your answer to give more details (if I can)